# Codeigniter defining variable in controller vs passing to model

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm wondering which method is better from a best practices perspective:

**Option 1:**

*Controller:*

```
$this->data['my_var'] = 'some value';
$response = $this->My_model->some_method();
```

*Model:*

```
function some_method()
{
    $var = $this->data['my_var'];
    //do stuff
}
```

**Option 2:**

*Controller:*

```
$this->data['my_var'] = 'some value';
$response = $this->My_model->some_method($this->data['my_var']);
```

*Model:*

```
function some_method($myVar)
{
    //do stuff with $myVar
}
```

Essentially the difference being passing the variable as a parameter, or defining the variable as a part of the data array and accessing it inside the model.

Comment: option 2 is more better

Comment: Option 2 is best..

Comment: if option 1 is really working (tested by you) then that is good, because it's already available to MODEL function so need to pass it again.

Comment: it's working. It's available to the model bc I've set the data array to public.

Comment: for the 2nd one also, data array is define as public?

Comment: In general, you should drift away from globals and make use of dependency injection.

Comment: Agreed with @FirstOne , so try to avoid public declaration and go for 2nd one if you can pass and able to access it as a function paramter (test that)

Comment: ok that makes sense. dependency injection it is!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 2 is best

In option 1 the property `$data` must be public to be visible in the model. Also possible source of bugs if the model has a property named `$data` too.